# jplayer change background on pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jplayer

I am having some trouble with my Jplayer which is an audio player. I am having trouble accessing isPaused. What I need to have happen is the background image of a div needs to change when the player is playing. I have two test scripts, neither are working proper.

My player

```
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
    {
        mp3: "/media/audio/RelaxSeg.mp3",
    }, {
        supplied: "mp3",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
        swfPath: "/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/js",
        wmode: "window"
});
```

My containter.

```
  <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="cp-jplayer"></div>
  <div id="cp_container_1" class="cp-container" style="background:none;">
    <img id="bg_image" class="bg_image1"  src="/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_img.png" height="60"  />
        <div class="cp-progress-holder"> <!-- .cp-gt50 only needed when progress is > than 50% -->
            <div class="cp-progress-1"></div>
            <div class="cp-progress-2"></div>
        </div>

    <div class="cp-circle-control"></div>
         <ul class="cp-controls">
             <li><a id="play1"  class="cp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
             <li><a id="pause1"  class="cp-pause" style="display:none;" tabindex="1">pause</a></li> <!-- Needs the inline style here, or jQuery.show() uses display:inline instead of display:block -->
         </ul>


  </div>
```

This should work, but for some reason doesnt.

```
if($("#jquery_jplayer_1").data("jPlayer").status.isPlaying) { 
    $(".bg_image1").attr("src", "/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_image_green.png"); 
    } 
    else { 
    $(".bg_image1").attr("src", "/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_img.png");
    }
```

I also have this code that doenst work either, when the player is not playing, the pause button is not displayed, and when the player is playing, its style becomes display=block.

```
if(document.getElementById("pause1").style.display = "block") { 
    $(".bg_image1").attr("src", "/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_image_green.png"); 
    } 

if(document.getElementById("pause1").style.display = "none") { 
    $(".bg_image1").attr("src", "/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_img.png");
    }
```

I appologize for the block of code, but I didnt want to leave anything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the `play`, `pause` and `end` events in jPlayer by doing something like:

```
var myCirclePlayer = new CirclePlayer("#jquery_jplayer_1",
{
    mp3: "/media/audio/RelaxSeg.mp3",
}, {
    supplied: "mp3",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#cp_container_1",
    swfPath: "/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/js",
    wmode: "window",
    play: function () {
        $(".bg_image1").attr("src", "/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_img.png");
    },
    pause: function () {
        $(".bg_image1").attr("src", "/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_image_green.png");
    },
    ended: function () {
        $(".bg_image1").attr("src", "/jQuery.jPlayer.2.2.0/v11/circle.skin/jplayer_bg_image_green.png");
    }
   });
```

Comment: That actually doesnt change on the end of the audio. When the audio ends, the player also needs to change the background, that is why I need a function that works with isPlaying

Comment: @user2089255 I think you need `playing` and **not** `isPlaying` (`isPlaying` doesn't exist)

Comment: @user2089255 Check my updated edit, you can also use the `ended` event to see when it's ended.

Comment: @user2089255 No problems, glad I could help! jPlayer can be a nightmare sometimes :)